# Do all guild members receive rewards from guild fest, or just those above castle level 15?

Tags: lords-mobile

Guild fest requires that you be castle level 15 to enter, and the interface for it is disabled before you are castle level 15.  We are a young guild with only a few members at castle level 15 and I'm wondering if it's worth pushing for the few of us that could contribute to reach tier 1.  If we do make it to reward tier 1 will all members of the guild be able to claim rewards (46 of us) or just those of us who could take part (3 of us)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only those guild members able to take part in the guildfest are able to claim rewards.  However, it does appear that if a castle becomes eligible during the guildfest period, they are immediately able to take part and still claim rewards.

This is disappointing, as it seemed like another way stronger and more experienced guild members could help their weaker guildies grow.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t correct, if you become eligible for guildfest halfway through the event you can’t’ participate until the next time it is held